# What is the grammar error in this sentence: "We should spend more money on education and health and fewer on new technology"?

Tags: word-choice, countability

The following sentence isn't grammatically correct and I don't know why ?

> We should spend more money on education and health and fewer on new
>   technology.

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Money" is uncountable, so the correct sentence is:

"We should spend more money on education and health and **less** on new technology."

Comment: Uncountable - also known as a "[mass noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mass%20noun?s=t)."

Answer (score 7):

Conversely, the same idea can be expressed as

> We should spend more dollars on education and fewer on new technology.

**More** is acceptable for both countable and not countable.

> More beans and more water.

But

> Fewer beans and less water

Comment: But note that "more dollars on education and fewer on new technology" is something of a special case because you're effectively talking about the dollars individually. Conversely to your converse, "We should spend a million dollars on education and *less* on new technology."

Comment: You're making the mistake of thinking that because mass nouns can only take 'less', that countable nouns shouldn't take 'less'. 'Less' is like 'more': it's allowed for both mass and countable, but 'fewer' is only allowed for countables.

Comment: @curiousdannii though there are plenty of teachers and would-be pedants that make that mistake too, so it's a "zombie rule". While you are 100% correct, it can be worth knowing that some object to *less* for countables, if only so that one knows not to worry about them.

Comment: -1. The first sentence sounds like you're going to spend about 6 fewer dollars on technology, all of them one dollar bills.

Answer (score 1):

We say ***less* money** not *fewer* money because it is a  mass noun (uncountable). The noun *money*  can also be omitted when it is inferred by the verb *spend*.

1. I should spend LESS [money] on eating out and MORE on books.

But units of money such as euros, dollars, coins, cents, etc. are **countable**, and it is considered grammatically more acceptable to use *few/fewer*. The unit of money cannot be omitted in this case

2. I should spend FEWER DOLLARS on eating out and more on books.

> **[Uncountable nouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-nouns/nouns-countable-and-uncountable)**
>
> ---
>
> In English grammar, some things are seen as a whole or mass. These are called uncountable nouns, because they cannot be separated or counted.
>
> Other common uncountable nouns include:
>   *accommodation*, *baggage*, *homework*, *knowledge*, ***money***, *permission*, *research*, *traffic*, *travel*.
>   <sub>*Cambridge Dictionaries*</sub>